# How to close DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, connect

Im using connect-domain to handle the errors for DB connection. When no data is found in DB, connect-domain throws the error. Below is the code

```
db.store.find({'_id':id},function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error("error");
        }
        else if (data == null) {
            throw new Error("data not present in DB");
            // DB connection close
        }
        else
        {
        console.log(data);
        });
```

But I want DB connection also to be closed when such errors occur.

Any help on this will be really helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using native mongo driver for node or mongoose? If you're using the native drive, just close the connector.

```
var connector = new mongodb.Db(dbName, mongodb.Server('127.0.0.1', 27017));
.
.
.
connector.close();
```

If you're using mongoose, it'll take care of the connection for you.